# LSTM time-series prediction separating dependent variable and independent variables

Tags: time-series, lstm, prediction

Most of the LSTM tutorials I have seen are using "dependent variable" in the "independent variable" as well for the LSTM model.

For instance, I want to predict pollution. The other variables such as dew,  temp,   press, wnd_dir,  wnd_spd,  snow, rain are independent variables of pollution. But from this [tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/), they are using the "pollution" variable as one of their "independent variables" for LSTM.

How can we adjust the code? so we can only predict using the other independent variables without the "pollution" variable.

Comment: You can use [this](https://ai4water.readthedocs.io/en/latest/utils/#ai4water.utils.utils.prepare_data) function to prepare your data for time series prediction problem

Comment: @Ather Cheema this is what I'm looking for. Thank you so much. I will try it out!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.